# Detect whether it is a login redirect on session expiry

Tags: single-sign-on

In case of a hybrid app using SAML based third party IDP.When the salesforce session expire or IDP session expire how do we detect ? In current SDK in SFHybridViewController for Non SSO case they detect login redirect using presence of 301/302 and start URL and then start ouath flow in separate webview. How do we detect in case of an external IDP using SAML ?